# Form for submitting multiple fields

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I want to create a form which has 10 titles, 10 body and 10 images inside it. Like Instagram but captions are different for every picture. I want to insert it into an array of each. An array of title containing 10 titles, an array of bodies and so on for each part of the post. In the model schema, I created an array like such:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:[{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }],
    body:[{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }],
    photo:[{
        type:String,
        require:false
    }],
    postedBy:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }
})
mongoose.model('Post',postSchema)
```

In the routes file

```
router.post('/createpost',requireLogin,(req,res)=>{
    const {title=[],body=[],pic=[]} = req.body 
    if(!title[0] || !body[0]){ //atleast 1 body and 1 title should be present
    return  res.status(422).json({error:"Please add all the fields"})
    }
    
    const post = new Post({
        title[],
        body[],
        photo:pic[],
        postedBy:req.user
    })
    post.save()
    .then(result=>{
        res.json({post:result})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

but this is certainly not right
Also, how to stop this at 10 fields only

Answer (score 1):

Stopping it at 10 fields is more of a front-end question. This:

```
title:[{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }]
```

will allow you to enter an unlimited array of strings.

Now, as for saving your titles, bodies and pics, you are really close. Just change your code to:

```
...
const post = new Post({
        title,
        body,
        photo:pic,
        postedBy:req.user
    })
    post.save()
    .then(result=>{
        res.json({post:result})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
...
```

Comment: @hereforadoubt Awesome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.